# Can we do sthapna of vigrah at home during Chaturmas?

Tags: astrology, festivals, pranapratishtha

Can we do sthapna of vigraha(Radha Krishna Pratima) at home during [Chaturmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaturmas)?

Some said you cannot do any kind of sthapana/pran-pratishtha during these 4 months.

Some said only muhurta karyas like weddings, laying of ceiling, etc are prohibited but murti sthapna for home mandir can be done. We are thinking of doing Radha Krishna Pratima sthapna on janmashtami on 30th August, 2021